# Selects hierárquicos. Relação pai-filho na mesma tabela

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tenho uma Entidade Product com relação @ManyToOne. E preciso trazer o ultimo registro filho de cada pai.
Fiz um select na tabela e esta trazendo o que eu preciso mais não estou acertado fazer a mesma consulta com hql.

Esse e meu select no mysql:

```
SELECT p1.id,p1.description,p1.code,p1.note,p1.owner_id FROM
product AS p1 LEFT JOIN product AS p2
ON p1.id = p2.owner_id
WHERE p2.owner_id IS NULL;
```

E essa consulta e como estou tentando fazer no hql:

```
("SELECT E FROM " +  Product.class.getSimpleName()
                + " E LEFT JOIN " +  Product.class.getSimpleName()
                + " P ON E.id = P.owner_id"
                + " P WHERE P.owner_id IS NULL");
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tente mudar sua hql para:

```
("SELECT E FROM " +  Product.class.getSimpleName() + " AS E"
    + " LEFT JOIN " +  Product.class.getSimpleName() + " AS P"
    + " ON E.id = P.owner_id"
    + " WHERE P.owner_id IS NULL");
```

Comment: Ola os AS não faz diferença.

Comment: Sim, outra opcao no lugar do `AS` é colocar o nome da variável direto, mais ai é um critério pessoal. `"SELECT E FROM " +  Product.class.getSimpleName() + " E"
    + " LEFT JOIN " +  Product.class.getSimpleName() + " P"`]